# How to add bin script to Angular's ng-package generated library

Tags: angular, npm, angular-library, ng-packagr

Inside Angular library project I have a script

```
  "bin": {
    "some-script": "./.bin/some-script.js"
  },
```

but when I build the project with :

```
ng build project-name --prod
```

then `some-script.js` is not included in the output (dist folder) nor in the package (`npm pack`).

How can I add it to the `dist` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it as an asset of the `ng-packagr` configuration.

**ng-package.json**

```json
{
    "assets": [
        ".bin/some-script.js"
    ],
    "lib": {
        ...
    }
}
```

More info: https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/copy-assets.md